# How to get the background in setter?

Tags: wpf

how to get the background of a control in the setter. Eg. How to the get the Background of TextBox in the Setter?

```
 <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
```

This statement will give an error "Expression type is note valid style value". Is there any way to get the background property in the setter?

Comment: You can only use a `TemplateBinding` from within a control template - only a style within a template will work.  What's the rest of your Xaml?

Comment: my requirement is, i want to set the TextBox background from code behind and it should display in the Border Control.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
<Style TargetType={x:Type TextBox}>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure" />
</Style>
```

Is this what you are trying ??

Sudarsan Srinivasan

**Update related to the first comment on this answer**

If you want to do ElementBinding,

Sudarsan Srinivasan

Comment: Okay, now I understand. Why don't you try ElementBinding in here,   

Something like,   
Binding ElementName=<Name of the Element>, Path=Background ...

What I am trying to suggest is you can bind a visual element's property to another element's property.